# Get a list of the last line of progress of each item sub-reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table a and b. In the table there are:
unique id for the article, sref1: for the sub-reference of the article and shortname of the article.
In table b, it's she who manages the completeness of the article with a history.
There is a unique identifier, the completenessProgression and completenessObject_id which refers to the identifier of table a.

Last row of table b in my progress field.
And in the same query it would take a sort without duplicate of the concat ("shortname", "-", "sub-reference").
So have in return for my request the for each article with its sub-reference the last progression to save.

Currently I know how to retrieve the last value of the progress for a specific article :

```
SELECT oo_id, completenessProgression, completenessObject__id 
FROM object_20 WHERE object_20.completenessObject__id=171423 
ORDER BY object_20.oo_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I also know how to retrieve articles by name and sub-reference1 with a GROUP BY :

```
SELECT object_20.oo_id AS Id, object_20.completenessObject__id AS id2,
object_20.completenessProgression AS Progress,
object_1.CSubRef1 AS Color, object_1.shortname AS Name
FROM object_20 INNER JOIN object_1
ON object_1.oo_id = object_20.completenessObject__id
WHERE object_20.completenessProgression >= 80
GROUP BY CONCAT(object_1.CSubRef1, ' ',object_1.shortname);
```

But when I add in my where clause a completenessProgression> 80.
It does not take the last values ​​of my completeness for each article by name and under reference.

I have tested with various sub-request but I cannot get something correct.
I can only use queries, no script, no trigger.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a51d/1

```
+------------------------------------+
| Results Completeness > 80          |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+
| Id  | Name     | Color  | Progress |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+
| 2   | Armand   | Jaune  | 98       |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+
| 4   | Herbert  | Bleu   | 100      |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+
```

---

*edit 30 November 2021*

The problem is that in my case I have a sub-reference 2 which is the size and I don't want this value because the progression is similar from one sub-reference 2 to another.

And the problem is there, I have as many lines as there are sizes while I only want one line per CSubRef1 and not one line per CSubRef2

If I'm not clear, I can make a screen of my current output. that's why in my case I made a:

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(object_1.CSubRef1, ' ',object_1.shortname);
```

but it doesn't work the way i would like

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a full [mre]

Comment: i don't get the 82 or armaund i would expect 98

Comment: oh yes syr my bad 98!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the numbers for progression are unique, what i doubt, you could use a subquery

But a better solution is the second, with a window function, because if you use the second and you have more than one, you need a similar solution

> ```
> SELECT o20.*,o1.CSubRef1 ,  o1.shortname 
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(completenessProgression) maxreg, shortname
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id
> GROUP BY shortname) t1 On t1.shortname = o1.shortname  AND  t1.maxreg = o20.completenessProgression
> WHERE o20.completenessProgression > 80
> ```
>
> ```
> oo_id | completenessProgression | completenessObject__id | CSubRef1 | shortname
> ----: | ----------------------: | ---------------------: | :------- | :--------
>     6 |                      98 |                      2 | Jaune    | Armand   
>     7 |                     100 |                      4 | Bleu     | Hebert
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     oo_id,CSubRef1,  shortname,completenessProgression
> FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shortname ORDER BY  completenessProgression DESC) rn
> ,o20.oo_id,CSubRef1,  shortname,completenessProgression
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id) t2
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> oo_id | CSubRef1 | shortname | completenessProgression
> ----: | :------- | :-------- | ----------------------:
>     6 | Jaune    | Armand    |                      98
>     7 | Bleu     | Hebert    |                     100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f2908616b28a25bb607245f2047f886)*

Everything is there you need only to bi8rng them to the public

> ```
> SELECT o20.completenessObject__id, o1.CSubRef1 ,  o1.shortname , o20.completenessProgression
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id
> INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(completenessProgression) maxreg, shortname
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id
> GROUP BY shortname) t1 On t1.shortname = o1.shortname  AND  t1.maxreg = o20.completenessProgression
> WHERE o20.completenessProgression > 80
> ```
>
> ```
> completenessObject__id | CSubRef1 | shortname | completenessProgression
> ---------------------: | :------- | :-------- | ----------------------:
>                      2 | Jaune    | Armand    |                      98
>                      4 | Bleu     | Hebert    |                     100
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     completenessObject__id,CSubRef1,  shortname,completenessProgression
> FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shortname ORDER BY  completenessProgression DESC) rn
> ,o20.oo_id,CSubRef1,  shortname,completenessProgression,completenessObject__id
> FROM object_20 o20 INNER JOIN object_1 o1 ON o1.oo_id = o20.completenessObject__id) t2
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> completenessObject__id | CSubRef1 | shortname | completenessProgression
> ---------------------: | :------- | :-------- | ----------------------:
>                      2 | Jaune    | Armand    |                      98
>                      4 | Bleu     | Hebert    |                     100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af1abe71809ea32ba01025b2a65861ab)*

Comment: I forgot to say that I had made an edit. FYI I tested with a left join but it doesn't do what I want at all.

Comment: it is basically the same query and you can pick every column as needed, that is basic sql